# Issue in custom font (RTL labguage)

Tags: android, right-to-left

According to [android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html) some RTL languages such as Arabic is supported in this new version. However, emulator does not show the fount correctly. In code I have written:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Larabieb.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
    txt.setTextSize(26);
    txt.setText("السلام علیک یا حبیبی");
}
```

but in the output it shows separated characters instead of connected characters.

[image]

How can I connect the characters?

Comment: have you pasted this "Larabieb.ttf", .ttf yourself in asset??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this date only Samsung's phones running on android support `bidi` and display of arabic characters. There is nothing wrong with your code. Open the w[eb browser and browse an arabic website](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_Mv9fjV6Oq3o/TP0VyvfoFEI/AAAAAAAAEzc/rZDJZHARtMs/s640/arghgoogle%5B1%5D.jpg) you will see the same problem on non-samsung phones.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [tools](https://github.com/smmoosavi/android-Farsi-Tools)

```
Tools.fa("سلام علیکم");
```

sample image:
[image]